# Vuejs | Как реализовать v-model для компонента

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Убрать у кнопки  `disabled` когда поля формы полностью заполнены (код из 6 цифр).

```
<InputCode v-model="value" />
<b-button @click.prevent="goToTest" variant="success" block :disabled="isInputCodeDisabled">Go</b-button>
```

В `data`:

```
isInputCodeDisabled: true,
```

Код самого компонента

```
<input
                :autofocus="n == 1"
                :disabled="isInputCodeDisabled"
                @keydown="inputKeydown"
                @focus="inputFocus"
                v-model="formCode[n-1]"
                @input="inputField"
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                autocomplete="off"
                placeholder="X"
            >
```

Как убрать у кнопки `disabled` когда заполнена форма?

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нужно задействовать 
[вычисляемые поля (computed)](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed).

Пример реализации:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input id="id" ref="price" v-model="price">
    <button :disabled="isInputCodeDisabled">calculate</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  computed:{
    // твоя логика здесь!!!
    isInputCodeDisabled(){
      return this.price.length < 6
    }
  },
  data(){
    return {
      price: 0
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: cпасибо за ответ. но к сожалению не удалось разобраться. передаю в v-model `formCode`, но не работает